# how to update group array when i create new group using ReactQuery useMutation

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I want to create a group and update my group list immediately but here I have to refresh the page and get fresh data

[image: fetch and create custom hooks]
[image: create group function in component level]

Comment: You should probably add your code snippets as text in your post to remove the amount of wrapped lines so it's easier for others to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good, but you probably want an optimistic update: Update the groups locally before the request happens, and then potentially rollback when an error occurs. This is covered in the [docs here](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/optimistic-updates). In your case, something like:

```
useMutation(
  values => createGroup(values),
  {
    onMutate: async value => {
      await queryClient.cancelQueries('groups')
 
      const previousGroups = queryClient.getQueryData('groups')
 
      queryClient.setQueryData('groups', old => [...old, value])
 
      return { previousGroups }
    },
    onError: (err, values, context) => {
      queryClient.setQueryData('groups', context.previousGroups)
    },
    onSettled: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries('groups')
    }
  }
)
```

you can also omit the refetch in onSettled if your optimistic update is considered to be correct, or you can return data from the server and put that in the cache in `onSuccess`.